# Display Message if Flash Doesn't Show in IE8

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer-8

Okay...so apparently with the new update in IE8, it starts up with NO add-ons.  Since I cannot program a code to turn on add-ons in a browser, I need to show a message when this occurs.  Much like an image has alternative text in the event the image doesn't load...how can I add a message that states:

> You are using Internet Explorer 8+ and need to turn on your add-ins like FLASH Player. This site is optimized for Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome.

ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<object ...>
<param ... />
You are using a browser that does not have Flash player enabled.
Please turn on your Flash player plugin.
</object>
```

This will display the appropriate message to any visitor (whether they're using IE8 or another browser) if they have Flash disabled.

Alternatively, you could use swfobject.js or similar, which will insert the Flash movie into a `<div>`.  And if Flash is unavailable, the content that is already inside the `<div>` will be displayed instead.

Comment: The flash is embedded...Div does not work and neither does just injecting it after params and before /object.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: So, how the hell will I do the swfobject.js....I'm ready the documentation, but I don't know exactly how/where to put it...will be playing around with it.

Comment: Okay...so, been playing around, used the documentation and the HTML Generator but now it's not playing at all in IE or Firefox/Chrome.

Where'd I go wrong?
<p>
In the <head> tag: <br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   swfobject.registerObject("FishChummer", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
  </script>

Comment: <div>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="650" id="FishChummer">
    <param name="movie" value="FishChummer.swf">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FishChummer.swf" width="800" height="650">
    <!--<![endif]-->
     If you are seeing this message, you are either using a browser that requires you to turn Flash Player ON, or you have an outdated version of Flash Player.  Update your Flash Player with the link below.<p>
     <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">

Comment: <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
     </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
   </object>
  </div>

Comment: What happens when you use the simple method in my answer?  Need more info than "does not work"... what do you see where the Flash should be?  Is there any error message?

Comment: No errors, just NOTHING.  It doesn't display the alt text or anything.

Comment: Okay, go to http://www.fishchummer.com with IE8 and you'll see what it does...then go to it in another browser.  I cannot seem to get it to work, the flash shows up for about 2 seconds, then vanishes...and NO alt text.

Comment: Does IE8 have problems with STOP actionscript 3.0?  Because it's almost like it runs through so quickly that it doesn't have time to load everything.

Comment: So, temporary fix, because I've used the simple preloader now from http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/699675 and it doesn't load at all...check it out.  But I still would like to get Flash working properly in IE.